# Programmatically create a user account

Tags: users, 8

I know that I can programmatically create a user using the following code, in Drupal 7.

```
$new_user = array(
  'name' => $name,
  'pass' => $sifra, // note: do not md5 the password
  'mail' => $email,
  'status' => 1,
  'init' => $email,
  'roles' => array(
    DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user',
    3 => 'custom role',
  ),
);

// The first parameter is sent blank so a new user is created.
user_save('', $new_user);
```

What is the equivalent code in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the suiting entity class. In case of a user it would be `Drupal\user\Entity\User`and you can use it as follows:

```
Drupal\user\Entity\User::create([
  'name' => $name,
  'pass' => $sifra,
  …
])->save();
```

Make sure to check the *Create* section on [Working with the Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/node/2124403).

Comment: can I use this code in custom module ?

Comment: Sure, this is standard code and therefor not protected by any copyright ;)

Answer (score 14):

For Drupal 8, the code to create a user entity is the following one.

```
$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::create();

// Mandatory.
$user->setPassword('password');
$user->enforceIsNew();
$user->setEmail('email');
$user->setUsername('user_name');

// Optional.
$user->set('init', 'email');
$user->set('langcode', $language);
$user->set('preferred_langcode', $language);
$user->set('preferred_admin_langcode', $language);
$user->set('setting_name', 'setting_value');
$user->addRole('rid');
$user->activate();

// Save user account.
$result = $user->save();
```

The code can be found on [Create a user account programmatically in Drupal 8](http://drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/13/create-a-user-account-programmatically-drupal-8).

Comment: `User::create()` also accepts an associative array for the initial values, too (all entities do).

Answer (score 3):

**For beyond Drupal 8.3.**

```
<?php

use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

// Create user object.
$user = User::create();

//Mandatory settings
$user->setPassword("password");
$user->enforceIsNew();
$user->setEmail("email");
$user->setUsername("username"); //This username must be unique and accept only a-Z,0-9, - _ @ .
$user->addRole('role_name'); //E.g: authenticated
```

To Set custom field values

```
$user->set("field_machine_name", 'value');
```

Comment: This still requires a `$user->save();`

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I used to migrate old Drupal 6 user records to Drupal 8. I used the *entity_type.manager* service to create user entities.

```
$values = [
  'name'                     => $data['name'],
  'pass'                     => $data['pass'],
  'mail'                     => $data['mail'],
  'init'                     => $data['init'],
  'status'                   => $data['status'],
  'timezone'                 => $data['timezone_name'],
  'created'                  => $data['created'],
  'access'                   => $data['access'],
  'login'                    => $data['login'],
  'langcode'                 => $data['language'],
  'preferred_langcode'       => $data['language'],
  'preferred_admin_langcode' => $data['language'],
];

if (!empty($data['picture'])) {
  $file_remote_url = $remoteBaseUrl . $data['picture'];
  $file_content = file_get_contents($file_remote_url);
  $file_name = basename($data['picture']);
  $file_uri = 'public://' . $file_name;

  if (!empty($file_content)) {
    $file = file_save_data($file_content, $file_uri, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
    if ($file) {
      $values['user_picture'] = $file->id();
    }
  }
}

/** @var \Drupal\user\Entity\User $entity */
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('user')
  ->create($values);
$entity->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 8 I use this code to create a user with a predefined uid and an already hashed password from Drupal 7:

```
        $user = User::create(array(
          'uid' => $data[0],
          'name' => $data[1],
          'pass' => $data[2],
          'mail' => $data[3],
          'status' => $data[4],
          'access' => $data[6],
          'login' => $data[7],
          'timezone' => $data[8],
          'langcode' => $data[9],
          'preferred_langcode' => $data[9],
          'preferred_admin_langcode' => $data[9],
          'init' => $data[10],
        ));
        $user->created = $data[5];
        $roles = explode(",", $data[11]);
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
          switch ($role) {
            case 3:
              $user->addRole('administrator');
              break;

            case 4:
              $user->addRole('contributeur');
              break;

            case 6:
              $user->addRole('admin_m2');
              break;
          }
        }
        // Save user account.
        $user->save();

        $database = \Drupal::database();
        // Dirty overwrite of the re-hashed hash.
        $database->merge('users_field_data')
          ->fields(['pass' => 'YOUR_D7_HASH_HERE'])
          ->keys(array('uid' => $data[0]))
          ->execute();
```