# Can user UUID be null?

Tags: users

I have a Drupal 7 site with a bunch of users. I want to migrate the users to Drupal 8 but not any of the content so I'm writing a crosswalk. Drupal 8 has uuid in the users table. Is there a way I can compute this or can I just set it to NULL? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, cannot be empty.

You can generate one with

```
$uuid_service = \Drupal::service('uuid');
$uuid = $uuid_service->generate();
```

If you use [User::create](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185441/programmatically-create-a-user-account) it will automatically generate one for you.

```
Drupal\user\Entity\User::create([
  'uid' => $uid,
  'name' => '$user_name,
  'mail' => $email,
  'roles' => [],
  'pass' => [
    'value' => $hashed_drupal_7_password,
    'pre_hashed' => TRUE,
  ],
  'status' => 1,
])->save();
```

---

Rather than code it from scratch. The proper, Drupal way, to migrate is
using all of these:

- core's migrate
- [migrate plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus)
- [migrate tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools)

I suggest your read this article [A Quick Guide to Migrating Drupal Content from D7 to D8](https://blog.thebrickfactory.com/2019/09/a-quick-guide-to-migrating-drupal-content-from-d7-to-d8/) which goes over how to migrate users and other scenarios.

Comment: Even easier, I discovered the Universally Unique IDentifier module for Drupal 7. That generated uuids that I can just port over.